# View not returning ID

Tags: django

I have a view that requires two `args` to be provided. `Project_id` and `Questionnaire_ID`

There is a `Project` and `Questionnaire` model.

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
```

```
class Project(models.Model):

    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    project_website = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    project_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I have a project details page, which is basically just a project landing page and from there I have a link to the questionnaire.

the link is formed via a `For` loop

```
{% for item in questionnaire %}
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'questions' project.id questionnaire.id %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}">Questionnaire</a>
{% endfor %}
```

and my url conf is `path('questions/<int:project_id>/<int:questionnaire_id>', view=add_fundamental_answers_view, name="questions"),`

but when i load the project_details page i get an error

```
Reverse for 'questions' with arguments '(1, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questions/(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<questionnaire_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

So it looks like the questionnaire_id is not being past in, but i'm not sure why?

```
def add_fundamental_answers_view(request, project_id, questionnaire_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    questionnaire = Question.objects.filter(questionnaire_id=questionnaire_id)
    next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
    if request.method =='POST':
            formset = AnswersForm()(request.POST)
            if formset.is_valid():
                answer = formset.save(commit=False)
                answer.project_name = project
                answer.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
        form = AnswersForm()
    return render(request, 'pages/formset.html', {'project': project, "form": form,'questionnaire':questionnaire})
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the error, it says :  `with arguments '(1, '')'`

1st argument is `1`, second is `None/Empty`.
But, your url expects 2 arguments.

```
path('questions/<int:project_id>/<int:questionnaire_id>'...)
```

You need to change :

```
{% for item in questionnaire %}
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'questions' project.id questionnaire.id %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}">Questionnaire</a>
{% endfor %}
```

To this

```
{% for item in questionnaire %}
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'questions' project.id item.id %}?next={{ request.path|urlencode }}">Questionnaire</a>
{% endfor %}
```

instead of `questionnaire.id` use `item.id`.

Questionnaire is a queryset, instead you want the id of instance.